# Is anyone interested to set up a community for GeoDMS?

Tags: geospatial, gis, vesta

GeoDMS is a fairly obscure geographic object-oriented programming language written in C++ by Object Vision (http://www.objectvision.nl/geodms/). I'm using it to analyse location-dependent renewable energy options, with or without the Vesta model, also by Object Vision and the Dutch Environmental Planning Bureau (http://www.pbl.nl/).

I have frequent questions on how to do things in GeoDMS. If anyone else is working with this language, it would be great to exchange knowledge! Please respond to this threat. Thank you.

Comment: SO is not a forum, and questions are not threads. SO is for to-the-point questions with to-the-point answers. While I sympathize with your aim to exchange knowledge in this way, this is not the place. There are other communities out there for this purpose. If you have concrete questions about GeoDMS, feel free to ask them, but make sure you've taken the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

GeoDMS is now a tag with which you can find GeoDMS related Q&A here.